Grub won’t boot Windows 11
I have a NVMe drive dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 11.
On my BIOS (UEFI) there is the option to boot from the hard disk and another UEFI hard disk Windows Boot Manager.
When I boot into the hard disk, I get put into grub rescue.
Only hd0,gpt2 has a known file system and that's ext2
My.mod files are in /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/, but the system won't boot into grub as it’s looking in /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod
When I boot into my hard disk Windows Boot Manager, I go into grub2 and Ubuntu boots fine, but Windows just sends me back to Grub2.
In Grub Customizer I tried booting from the EFI system partition and the Microsoft basic partition. When I boot from the Microsoft Basic Partition I get the following error message.


I do not recommend Customizer, it sometimes creates added issues. And it totally replaces grub with its own proxy files. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Are you booting in UEFI boot mode? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ total uninstall & reinstall of grub is the only way to remove Customizer

@oldfred this was helpful. Thanks


Create Ubuntu bootable media, boot from it and select the Try Ubuntu option.

Run the following commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair


Read Boot Info Summary.

Run Recommended repair.

Make a copy of EFI partition closer to the start of disk >100

Boot into Windows and run this command:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi




Step 5 was unnecessary
